# Optimising the ASP.NET Core release bundle

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I have published a .net core 2.0 api bundle with

```
dotnet publish -c release
```

The release folder includes a bunch of DLL's that I didn't think would be required for running the application, ie, code generation packages etc.

Is there a way to optimise the release package so that these dll's aren't included?

```
Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Workspaces.dll
Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspaces.dll
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational.Design.dll
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Design.dll
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Contracts.dll
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Core.dll
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.EntityFrameworkCore.dll
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Templating.dll
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Utils.dll
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.dll
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGenerators.Mvc.dll
NuGet.Frameworks.dll
System.Composition.AttributedModel.dll
System.Composition.Convention.dll
System.Composition.Hosting.dll
System.Composition.Runtime.dll
System.Composition.TypedParts.dll
dotnet-aspnet-codegenerator-design.dll
```

My csproj file:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="Models\" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.All" Version="2.0.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="2.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="2.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="2.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Design" Version="1.1.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="2.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="2.0.1" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools" Version="2.0.1" />
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet" Version="2.0.1" />
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.DotNet.Watcher.Tools" Version="2.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Comment: Don't put the tools & design packages in `PackageReference`but instead put them in `DotNetCliToolReference`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes.  Install the Microsoft.Packaging.Tools.Trimming NuGet package.  Then add this to your .csproj file:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <TrimUnusedDependencies>true</TrimUnusedDependencies>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Or use the /p:TrimUnusedDependencies=true flag from the command line.

```
dotnet build /p:TrimUnusedDependencies=true
dotnet publish /p:TrimUnusedDependencies=true
msbuild /p:TrimUnusedDependencies=true
msbuild /t:Publish /p:TrimUnusedDependencies=true
```

See [Dependency Trimming](https://github.com/dotnet/standard/blob/release/2.0.0/Microsoft.Packaging.Tools.Trimming/docs/trimming.md#how-to-use) documentation.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately the package hasn't been updated to .net core 2.0, but it solves the problem I had, will just wait until it's ready

Comment: Good point.  Well, things are moving pretty quickly with .NET Core.  Hopefully it's updated soon.